# Получить в запросе кастомной колонки

Tags: mysql

Есть некая таблица в БД, предположим такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как построить запрос, чтоб на выходе добавилось кастомное значение
[image: выходные данные]

Comment: `select id, name, 'Kyiv' as city from test`  или что?

Comment: или `alter table test add column city varchar(4) after name; update test set city = 'Kyiv'` ?

Comment: Именно)) Добавь эту строку как ответ, я отмечу как верную

Comment: Первый коммент добавь в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам необходимо выбрать некое значение в дополнение к набору данных, то просто допишите его к списку выборки, добавив нужный алиас столбца

```
SELECT id
     , name
     , 'Kyiv' as city 
FROM test
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось